# how to get the routes of my app in which my engine is mounted from the engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-engines

I want to list all the routes present in application from an engine through code written in engine, like fetching routes of application in application by using:

```
routes = Rails.application.routes.routes
routes.collect {|r| r.path.spec.to_s }
```

the above command lists down the routes available in main application

**1. What is the code to be used in engine to fetch the routes of application "in engine"?**

I'm not able to fetch the routes if I use the above code in engine

Comment: I’m not at a computer, but your Engine has a class name to it. Something like GemName::Engine. Try using the engine class instead of Rails in the above method calls.

Comment: Did you check [6.3 Routes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#routes) guide for engine?

Comment: I tried that also, it throws an error undefined method 'application', but thanks - @Nate

Comment: I see the docs and the new answer. Dang. I was close. Haha

Answer (score 1):

In engine `Rails.application.routes.routes` will be routes of its parent application.

`YourEngineClass::Engine.routes.routes` will be routes of the engine (keep in mind that these will not have route prefix, that comes from main app)

**Update:** routes are available after app initialisation. For them to be available in rake, you need to make your task dependent on `:environment`:

```
namespace :your_engine do
  desc "test"
  task some_task: :environment do
    puts "Routes:"
    puts Rails.application.routes.routes.collect {|r| r.path.spec.to_s }.join("\n")
  end 
end
```

Comment: no, my question was not to get routes of Engine to get routes of app from engine, I tried using Rails.application.routes.routes in engine, I didn't gave me any defined resource routes eg: resources :books in app, if i use Rails.application.routes.routes in engine I'm not able to fetch routes of books controller @vasfed

Comment: @NarayananV engine runs in the same ruby process, there's nothing stopping you from accessing these once the app is initialised and has loaded routes. If that's not working - please give more context on when you're trying to access these

Comment: ok, I have created a rake task in engine, i'm trying to access the app routes from that task file @vasfed

Comment: @NarayananV app needs to be loaded, rake by default does not load it, you need your task to be dependent on `:environment`

Comment: it's already made to be dependent on :environment ```namespace :user_namespace do
  desc "load new routes"
  task routes_setup: :environment do                                    
  route_details = Rails.application.routes.routes.map do |route|{ path: route.path.spec.to_s, controller: route.defaults[:controller], action: route.defaults[:action] }
    end``` @vasfed

Comment: sorry for the illegiblity, the point even though i put it under :environment its not fetching the routes - @vasfed

Comment: just tried your code in a mounted engine - and it works

Comment: can you post it, the configuration that you made in both app and engine @vasfed